# Why can new threads access the UI?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await

Given the following method as example:

```
private async void F()
{
    button.IsEnabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

In this case, any code starting at `await` always occurs on another thread (edit: wrong) which presumably should not have access to the UI thread, similarly to desktop apps. In a similar situation, I recall having an exception such as:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

However, the example does not trigger any exception. Is this expected? Can I reliably write code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any code starting at await always occurs on another thread (non-UI thread, right?),

No, not at all. `await` does not kick off other threads. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that may help if you find this statement confusing.

What `await` *will* do is schedule the remainder of the method as a continuation to be run after the asynchronous operation completes (in this case, the asynchronous operation is just a timer firing). By default, `await` will capture a "context", which is `SynchronizationContext.Current` (or, if it is `null`, the context is `TaskScheduler.Current`). In this case, there's a UI `SynchronizationContext` that ensures the remainder of the `async` method will run on the UI thread.

Comment: To be certain, doesn't `Task.Delay` start a new thread? I recall a thread on SO where someone argued so.

Comment: @Avenicci: Nope. It just starts a timer. Last time I checked, there's one thread per app that handles all the timers together. And when the timer completes, its callback is called on a thread pool thread, which is used very briefly just to complete the `Task` returned from `Task.Delay`. But no new threads are created.

Comment: How can an async method terminate directly if `Task.Delay` uses the same thread?

Comment: @Avenicci: The calling thread doesn't *terminate* - it just returns.

Answer (score 1):

Code running on the UI thread has a `SynchronizationContext`. You can see that by printing `SynchronizationContext.Current`. Before you await something that context is captured and after the await your code resumes on that context which makes sure the continuation runs on the UI thread.

To get the behavior you're referencing, where the continuation is run on a `ThreadPool` thread you can disable the `SynchronizationContext` capturing by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
private async void FooAsync()
{
    button.IsEnabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

This code will raise the exception you expect.

> Is this expected? Can I reliably write code like this?

Yes and yes. Code using async-await will "do the right thing" by default. But if you do want to offload something to a `ThreadPool` thread you can use `Task.Run`.

Comment: I guess I was mistaken that the code beyond `await` runs on a different thread, so instead it is posted to the `SynchronizationContext`, used by the UI thread?

Comment: @Avenicci the continuation after Task.Delay completes is posted to the SC that makes sure it runs on the UI thread.